# Django - как правильно работать с cache?

Tags: django, кэширование, view, redis, memcached

Пытаюсь разобраться с тем как и где правильно организовывать кеширование.

Cобственно два вопроса.

1. Нормально ли так реализовывавать кеширование? Может лучше еще как-то можно? Кеширую только поход в БД. Или лучше сразу ответ как-то кешировать?

```
class PostsListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'pages/post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        posts_list_qs = cache.get('posts_list_qs')
        if not posts_list_qs:
            posts_list_qs = get_all_posts()
            cache.set('posts_list_qs', posts_list_qs)
        return posts_list_qs
```

2. Как лучше инвалидейтить этот кеш? Что если у меня десяток вьюшек/асинхронных функций и т.п.
   на посты ссылаются. В тупую ключи перечислять или как? У меня же все кверисеты разные могут быть, в тупую везде Post.objects.all() не писать же??? Значит и под разными ключами их сохранять.

Просто перечислять все ключи в сигналах? В общем посоветуйте как лучше с кешем работу организовывать пожалуйста.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def post_post_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    cache.delete('posts_list_qs')
    cache.delete('posts_data_for_api_qs')
    cache.delete('posts_data_for_views_qs')
    cache.delete('posts_data_for_email_sending_qs')
```

if created не указываю, иначе очистка кеша не срабатывает при изменении объектов, только при создании с нуля. это норм?

Comment: Для кеширования запросов к базе есть [cacheops](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops)

Comment: Кстати, нужно не забывать чистить кеш и при удалении объектов тоже

Comment: Для кеширования всего ответа есть встроенный FetchFromCacheMiddleware 
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/middleware/cache/

Answer (score 0):

> Нормально ли так реализовывавать кеширование? Может лучше еще как-то можно? Кеширую только поход в БД. Или лучше сразу ответ как-то кешировать

Да. Только чаще придется использовать ключи, например для кеширования "страницы" списка постов. Просто вынестите ключ кеша отдельно:

```
cache_key = f"post_list_page_{page_num}"
data = cache.get(cache_key)
...
```

> Значит и под разными ключами их сохранять.

Да, но Вы можете указать время кеша, для более специфичных наборов (например, отфильтрованных по десятку разных фильтров) вы можете ставить время кеша меньше.

> Просто перечислять все ключи в сигналах? В общем посоветуйте как лучше с кешем работу организовывать пожалуйста.

Вы можете вынести очистку части кеша в отдельный метод/функцию, и вызывать в админке по требованию (если выведите как кнопку), или в `management_command` в конце обработки, в общем где угодно после массивных изменений объектов. Лишний клик, действие, но тогда кеш не будет часто перезаписываться при создании кучи объектов.

Comment: «А как иначе?» — ну можно например кешировать готовый html-код вместо объектов из базы, можно использовать упомянутый мной cacheops чтобы не изобретать всё вручную, можно распаковать объекты в простые словари и кешировать уже их (это теоретически может быть эффективнее) — в общем, много чего можно, если пофантазировать

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, в первый раз когда читал вопрос, прочитал как "кешировать данные бд" на не "кеширую пока данные бд". В этом случае, ответ получается неполным